My superset container in docker container is stopping again and again
I have a superset container in my docker. It keeps on stopping again and again. While i check my logs, it says pkg-config: not found.
My docker compose.yml looks something like this:
version: '3.9'
services:
  superset:
    image: apache/superset:latest
    container_name: superset
    ports:
    - "8080:8088"
    volumes:
    - ./superset_config.py:/app/pythonpath/superset_config.py
    - ./requirements.txt:/app/requirements.txt
    - ./.env-local:/app/.env
    command: >
      /bin/sh -c "pip install mysql-connector-python==8.0.31 && superset run -p 8088 --with-threads --reload --debugger"
    entrypoint: ["sh", "-c", "pip install -r /app/requirements.txt && superset run -p 8088 --with-threads --reload --debugger"]
    environment:
    - SUPERSET_ENV=development
    - EMBEDDED_SUPERSET=true
    - ENABLE_REACT_CRUD_VIEWS=true
    - SUPERSET_DB_URI=mysql+mysqlconnector://root:xxxxxx@host.docker.internal:3307/eeyedata
    - SUPERSET_HOME=/app/superset_home
    - SECRET_KEY=iA_YG5mnjn9jnxFjsbxb12f@tftv%hVFgyx3x4t*bhv^g3v!bhvg8stft7vojxjb75hVDrvfg0VTTVCTSyftfC7TG&vbxYGY6kjr5
    networks:
    - superset_superset_network
    depends_on:
    - mysql # Ensure MySQL is started before Superset

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxx
      MYSQL_DATABASE:aaaaa
    ports:
    - "3307:3306"
    networks:
    - superset_superset_network

networks:
  superset_superset_network:
    driver: bridge

my superset_config.py file looks like this:
FEATURE_FLAGS = {
"EMBEDDED_SUPERSET": True
}

i have tried restarting docker and downloading the dependencies from chrome.

What code is actually running in the container?  Overriding entrypoint: to try to reinstall software every time you run the container isn't typically the best approach; can you RUN pip install ... in a custom Dockerfile instead?  An error like pkg-config: not found implies you'll need additional OS-level packages, which again will be easier to do in a Dockerfile.
